# Is there any way to make WebStorm open one type of files in one tab and another type in a different tab?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I frequently wind up working with JS and CSS files alongside each other since we've adopted css-modules at work. It's an annoyingly tedious task for me to have to constantly reorder my tabs in WebStorm (well PhpStorm, but same difference).

Is there any way I can make all my JavaScript files open on the left hand side and my CSS files on the right hand side? I've tried looking in the preferences and plugins, but I can't find anything. Is there no hope?

Comment: There is no such option. The best I can suggest right now is to use "Move to opposite splitter" kind of actions after you open file in a wrong group/splitter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in WebStorm; please vote for [IDEA-111190](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111190) and linked tickets